# proving that $char(A) =p$ for some prime number $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A be an integral domain. If the order of $A$ is a prime number $p$, then the characteristic of $A$ must be equal to $p$.

Here's what I got so far. BY definition, for $a \in A, a \neq 0$, we know that the order of $a$ is the least positive integer such that $a^p =1$ (Since $A$ is a ring with unity)

$a^p = a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot ..... \cdot a = 1$ but I am stuck as to where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m$ be the order of $1$ in the additive group of $A$. By LaGrange's Theorem, $m$ must divide $\vert A \vert = p$. Therefore $m = 1$ or $m = p$. Since $A$ is not the zero ring, we must have $m = p$, hence $\textrm{char}(A) = p$.

It's worth noting that this also implies that $A$ is generated by $1$ as an additive group, hence $A \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: is the additive group of $A$ supposed to be a subgroup of $A$?

Comment: No, it is all of $A$. $A$ is a ring, therefore it is also an an abelian group under the addition operation.

Comment: OK. I am just confused because from my understanding, LaGrange's theorem essentially states that the order of any subgroup of a group $A$ is a divisor of the  order of $A$

Comment: Right, but a quick corollary to LaGrange's theorem is that the order of any element in a group divides the order of the group.